# Unable to change categorical data in one column (pandas, Machine Learning)

Tags: python

I have started with machine learning and already stuck on some task.
I want to set up (preprocessing) the table columns because the data in the columns are categorical. I have successfully process (change values) all columns except the last one. The data file from which I load (`dataset =  pd.read_csv("car.data")`) my values is car.data (I downloaded it from internet). To mention I am using pandas and all important libraries for ML (tensorflow, sklearn, numpy...).

When I run my code all columns are filled with numbers and only last one is filled with "None". I have noticed when I run: `dataset.unacc.unique()`, I get this output:
`array([None], dtype=object)` and it should not be of type object. In correct code is different: `array([0, 1, 3, 2], dtype=int64)`.

Can anyone help me with this problem? I couldn't find it on Internet. Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
dataset.unacc.unique()
```

This is function to change values in a column:

```
def label_fixTarget(something):
    if something=='unacc':
        return 0
    elif something=='acc':
        return 1
    elif something=='vgood':
        return 3
    elif something=="good":
        return 2
```

```
dataset['unacc'] = dataset['unacc'].apply(label_fixTarget)
dataset.unacc.unique()
dataset.head()
```

And this is my new table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you know the values to be changed, you can create a dictionary and map it on the column such as:

```
qualityToPoint ={
'TA' : 3,
'Fa' : 2,
'Gd' : 4,
'None': 0,
'Ex': 5,
'Po' : 1}

df['column'] = df['column'].map(qualityToPoint).astype('int')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to encode categorical data.

**To achieve what you want, you need to use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`.**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['unacc', 'acc', 'good', 'vgood']})

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

label_encoder.fit(df['a'])

# Putting in encoded categories into another column `encoded`
df['encoded'] = label_encoder.transform(df['a'])

print(df)
# This prints the following `df`
#        a  encoded
# 0  unacc        2
# 1    acc        0
# 2   good        1
# 3  vgood        3
```

`label_encoder` after the call to `fit` consists of all information about transforming categories to integers. Be careful it doesn't transform what it has not seen e.g. if I execute:

```
label_encoder.transform(['a', 'b'])
```

where neither 'a' nor 'b' was encountered during call to `fit`, it will result in exception.

**How to decode from integers back to labels:**

```
# Just like `transform`, we also have `inverse_transform`.
df['decoded'] = label_encoder.inverse_transform(df['encoded'])
print(df)
# This will print something like:
#        a  encoded decoded
# 0  unacc        2   unacc
# 1    acc        0     acc
# 2   good        1    good
# 3  vgood        3   vgood
```

So first I encoded column 'a' and put the encoded values into 'encoded' column. And then to test `inverse_transform`, I called inverse transform on the encoded values (values under 'encoded' column), and then put the result in 'decoded' column.

Column 'a' and 'decoded' should be same, and they're.

You can also print the classes that the `label_encoder` recognizes after the call to `fit`.

```
print(label_encoder.classes_)
# This will print
# array(['acc', 'good', 'unacc', 'vgood'], dtype=object)
```

Note: I put the results from `transform()` (which returns a `numpy.array`) into 'encoded' column in the same df  and the results from `inverse_transform()` into 'decoded' column just to demonstrate that the decoded values must be same as that of initial values.

[LabelEncoder scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works and now I have better accuracy.